# Firebase (Firestore) Javascript Keep showing error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Stuck for days now.
Codes are literally copied from the google firebase documentation.

All I want is just write and read data on firestore in firebase console.
Firebase (Firestore) Javascript Keep showing error.

Can anyone help me with code? I don't need fancy code or whatever. Just write and read from firestore that's it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import firebase from "firebase/app";
// If you are using v7 or any earlier version of the JS SDK, you should import firebase using namespace import
// import * as firebase from "firebase/app"

// If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics
import "firebase/analytics";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// For Firebase JavaScript SDK v7.20.0 and later, `measurementId` is an optional field
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "******",
    authDomain: "retest-5308a.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://retest-5308a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "retest-5308a",
    storageBucket: "retest-5308a.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "125780245080",
    appId: "1:125780245080:web:530259dc2a4b1362aae82d",
    measurementId: "G-PNTZS15X9K"
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");

// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "********",
    authDomain: "retest-5308a.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "retest-5308a"
  });
  
  var db = firebase.firestore();

  db.collection("users").add({
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please at least post the error?

Comment: Seems like there are multiple problems. When I fix some of it, error pops from somewhere else. Please check at this URL.   retest-5308a.firebaseapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `import firebase from "firebase/app";` inside a `script` tag in an HTML page.

Instead you should import those SDKs though their own `script` tags, as you've already done for `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js">` and `firebase-firestore.js`.

Once you've added the SDKs through `script` tags, the `imports` are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed both imports and require and it works perfectly.